# How do I have a dynamically updating Data Series for a scatter graph based on the below?

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have the below data, which is raw data, and I need the data series to be plotted by date. 
The x-axis is the location (kms) and the y_axis is one of the categories (such as Super Elev).

I can make it dynamically plot new data points through OFFSET, but I need it to be able to categorise them automatically into a new data series by data.

Can someone help?

Spreadsheet, new data is pasted continuously below, I need data series to be sorted automatically by date for the graph
[image]

Graphing data but not categorising into different data series based on date recorded
[image]

Comment: There are two pictures btw, sorry, new user to the site, one picture is the spreadsheet, the second is the graph. Thanks.

Comment: Pivot Chart was suggested below - Pivot Chart does not work as it classifies the Location KM as text, that's how Pivots work. This does not suit my purposes as I need the graph to display only a range from 227.4KM to 227.9KM. 

With a Pivot Chart, you cannot do this as it reads every location KM as a label/category.

Answer (score 0):

Create a pivot chart from the data. If you create an Excel table from the data first, then you can simply add new data and then update the pivot table.

[image]

A pivot chart cannot be an XY chart, but that does not mean you can't use an XY chart with data from a pivot table. You can build the pivot table, then define dynamic ranges with formulas that grow and shrink with the pivot table. Then you can use these range names in the series definition of a regular XY chart.

Creating regular charts from pivot table data is a topic that has been discussed and presented in many articles on the web. Try this article by Jon Peltier as a starting point. http://peltiertech.com/regular-charts-from-pivot-tables/

Comment: Pivot Chart doesn't work as it classifies the Location KMs as text as Pivot is dependent upon 'Labels'. This means, I cannot define the graph to display only a specific range from 227.4KM to 227.9KM. If only Pivot Chart could use Numeric data for the x-axis!!!

Comment: I have added some information about creating regular charts from pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code would be like this,

```
Sub setScatterChart()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Dim vX1(), vX2(), vY1(), vY2(), vDate()
    Dim vDB, n As Long, k As Long, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim myDate1 As Date, myDate2 As Date
    Dim X As New Collection


    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set Cht = Ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    vDB = Ws.UsedRange
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        Err.Clear
        X.Add vDB(i, 2), CStr(vDB(i, 2))
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            cnt = cnt + 1
            ReDim Preserve vDate(1 To cnt)
            vDate(cnt) = vDB(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    With Cht
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        For i = .SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
            .SeriesCollection(i).Delete
        Next i

        For j = 1 To cnt
            n = 0
            For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
                If vDB(i, 2) = vDate(j) Then
                    n = n + 1
                    ReDim Preserve vX1(1 To n)
                    ReDim Preserve vY1(1 To n)
                    vX1(n) = vDB(i, 11)
                    vY1(n) = vDB(i, 4)
                End If
            Next i
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With .SeriesCollection(j)
                    .Name = Format(vDate(j), "dd/mm/yyyy")
                    .XValues = vX1
                    .Values = vY1
            End With
        Next j
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: I haven't been able to try this. But, could you explain what it is exactly doing?

It does not appear to be dynamic? I.e. if someone copy pastes new data below the existing data, how does it automatically define a new series?

Comment: If  your all  data  started from  a2  cell,a1cell  is  field  namme.   Where  specific two day in  days is  graphed. X is location, Y is super eleve.

Comment: @stupidfish: I misunderstand your intention. I modified my code.